# If $W_1,W_2$ are independent and $P(W_1)=P(W_2)$, does $P(W_2|W_1)=P(W_1)=P(W_2)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know this problem is on Math SE, but my question has nothing to do with the mathematics itself but rather the intuition/"feel" for the problem. Specifically, my question is on part (b) and (c).

> You are going to play $2$ games of chess with an opponent whom you have
> never played against before (for the sake of this problem). Your
> opponent is equally likely to be a beginner, intermediate, or a
> master. Depending on which, your chances of winning an individual game
> are $90$%, $50$%, or $30$%, respectively.

(a) What is your probability of winning the first game?

Let $W_1$ be the event "win first game"; let $B$ be the event "chose beginner"; same for $I,M$.  We want to find $P(W_1)$. We use the law of total probability: $$P(W_1) = P(W_1|B)P(B)+P(W_1|I)P(I)+P(W_1|M)P(M) = \frac{1}{3}(0.9+0.5+0.3) = \frac{17}{30}$$

(b) Congratulations: you won the first game! Given this information, what is the probability that you will also win the second game (assume that, given the skill level of your opponent, the outcomes of the games are independent)?

Let $W_2$ be the event "win second game." We want to find $P(W_2|W_1)$. $$P(W_2|W_1) = \frac{P(W_2\cap W_1)}{P(W_1)}$$ We know the denominator from (a). We want to find the numerator. $$P(W_2\cap W_1) = P(W_2, W_1 | B)P(B) + P(W_2, W_1 | I)P(I) + P(W_2, W_1 | M)P(M) = $$$$ \frac{1}{3}(P(W_2, W_1 | B) + P(W_2, W_1 | I) + P(W_2, W_1 | M)) = \frac{1}{3}(.9^2+.5^2+.3^2) = \frac{23}{60}$$ Thus, we have $$P(W_2|W_1) = \frac{\frac{23}{60}}{\frac{17}{30}} = \frac{23}{34}$$

I know my answer is mathematically correct, but I'm still slightly confused intuitively. We know $P(W_1)=P(W_2)$ because $W_1,W_2$ are independent. If they're independent, the probability of $W_2$ shouldn't change if we know $W_1$ (by definition of independence). In other words, $P(W_2|W_1)=P(W_1)=P(W_2)$. Of course, this isn't true, but I'm wondering where my intuition is faulty.

(c) Explain the distinction between assuming that the outcomes of the games are independent and assuming that they are conditionally independent given the opponent’s skill level. Which of these assumptions seems more reasonable, and why?

I think my confusion on (c) stems from my confusion on (b).

Comment: I haven't read through all of your post yet, but the question in the title is an obvious yes.  Given that $A,B$ are independent and that $\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)$ we have that $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A)$ by independence which is further equal to $\Pr(B)$ by our hypothesis that they should be equal.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I agree. I think I'm missing a nuance in my title question that is a part of the problem. I'm quite certain it has to do w/ conditional independence and independence, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Now... reading your post, talking about winning a game against beginner, average, or master player etc... you are reading the problem incorrectly.  With $W_1$ the event that you win the first game and $W_2$ the event you win the second game, no $W_1$ is *not* independent of $W_2$.  If you won the first game you will have reason to believe that your opponent is unskilled and so are more inclined to believe that you will win the next game as well.

Comment: Read more carefully what they say... "**given** the skill level of your opponent, the outcomes of the games are independent"  That first half of the phrase is highly important.

Comment: Reemphasizing my previous comment... the phrase you are referring to includes additional necessary words preceding that which change the meaning of the sentence as a whole.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, thank you! The reason $W_1$ and $W_2$ are not independent is because we don't know what level our opponent is, right?

Comment: Yes.$~~~~~~~~~$